# How can I make XmlSerializer work with xsi:type?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have the following fairly simply XML that I'm trying to deserialize:

```
<props xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://foo.com/bar">
  <prop name="foo1" xsi:type="xsd:string">bar1</prop>
  <prop name="foo2" xsi:type="xsd:int">2</prop>
</props>
```

When I run XSD.exe over this XML to produce a schema and then run it again to produce C# classes, I end up with highly-decorated versions of the following:

```
public partial class props
{
    [XmlElement("prop", IsNullable = true)]
    propsProp[] Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class propsProp
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to deserialize the XML into these classes using XmlSerializer, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (4, 4). --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='string', namespace='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', at <prop xmlns='http://foo.com/bar'>.

The `xsi:type` attribute is presumably there to facilitate some polymorphism on the `prop` value, but I don't care about that - I just want the value in a C# property.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I get that XML into a C# class?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is going to work without a little extra effort, because the class cannot have a Value of `int` and `string` unless you used generics `(propsProp<T> - public T Value { get; set; }`.

Comment: That seems to suggest that `XmlSerializer` simply doesn't work with **xsi:type**?  If it helps any, I would be happy to just ignore it in my deserialization..?

Comment: So you'll never have to Serialize it back to the original XML ever?

Comment: In my case I won't.  (But good point.)

Answer (score 0):

I went through exactly the same issue and it's solution is pretty straightforward for reference predefined type but a little bit tricky for primitive types.

First what is the benefit of using Using `xsi:type`. I found this [link](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftxsityp.html) is so helpful and it helps me solving the issue.

So we use `xsi:type` in XML to refer to driven types, for example below:

```
 <X xsi:type="X1">
```

Means that X and X1 are driven types from each others, So i fixed the deserialization by using inheritance, via creating a new class for the child type and make it inherit from the parent, also we need to create a list of it:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "X1")]
    public class X1: X
    {
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "X1List")]
    public class X1List
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "X1")]
        public X1 X1{ get; set; }
    }
```

And in the other class which already uses X add also X1 as below:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Container")]
public class Container
{
    ...
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "XList")]
    public POCList XList{ get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "X1List")]
    public X1List X1List{ get; set; }
    ...
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
}
```

This should solves the deserialization.

For primitive types it will be a tricky but you can achieve the same solution using generics with constrains.